Getting error while implementing the trigger dispatcher architecture
when I am writing implementing class, I am getting the error

Error: Compile Error: Class signingFormHandler must implement the method: void ITriggerHandler.initialize(String) at line 1 column 14

Here is my class:
public class signingFormHandler implements ITriggerHandler{

    public void initialize(){
    
    }
    string str;
    public boolean Isdisabled(){
        return true;
    }
   

}

Here is my interface class:
public interface ITriggerHandler 
{

    void initialize(string parameter);
    void isDisabled(boolean bln);
    String getParameter();
    Map<String, Object> getParameterInfo();

    void bulkBeforeInsert(List<SObject> newItems);
    void beforeInsert(SObject newItem);

    void bulkBeforeUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems);
    void beforeUpdate(SObject oldItem, SObject newItem);
    
    void bulkBeforeDelete(Map<Id, SObject> oldItems);
    void beforeDelete(SObject oldItem);

    void bulkAfterInsert(Map<Id, SObject> newItems);
    void afterInsert(SObject newItem);
    
    void bulkAfterUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems);
    void afterUpdate(SObject oldItem, SObject newItem);
    
    void bulkAfterDelete(Map<Id, SObject> oldItems);
    void afterDelete(SObject oldItem);
    
    void andFinally();
}

Note: I have tried with abstract class not getting the error but from trigger I am not able to refer the abstract class.

When you have a class that implements an interface, you need to have all of the method signatures from that interface.
You can do that by writing each method, or by inheriting from another class that has some (or all) of those methods.
Specific to the error you're reporting here, your interface says you need a void initialize(String parameter), but the class you've written so far only has void initialize(). It's missing the String as a parameter. Thus the signature doesn't match your interface, and you get your error.
Since you haven't included the attempt at an abstract class, there's not much I can comment on there. What I can say is that abstract classes can contain virtual methods which you can supply a base/generic implementation for (and thus you wouldn't need to implement them in a subclass that extends that abstract class). abstract methods in an abstract class would all need to be implemented (similar to if you were using an interface).

and likewise, your signature for isDisabled() doesn't match the signature of the interface. The interface demands a Boolean parameter. Without more context, that doesn't make much sense (isDisabled should be internal state rather than something that just parrots back whatever it's passed), so it may be more appropriate to modify the interface to remove that as opposed to changing the implementing class.
